# Installing Python Packages Using Spyder

Tags: python, selenium, package, anaconda, spyder

I'd like to install Selenium for Python. I did  `pip install selenium`, and because it has already been installed, it returns: 'Requirement already satisfied.'

I use Spyder IDE, and when I `import selenium` in spyder console, it gives me an import error.

I am new to this, and I was wondering what I am missing. I also did `conda install -c conda-forge selenium` in the cmd as suggested [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/selenium), but it says conda is not a recognized internal or external command.

Comment: You are encountering path issues. You probably do not have anaconda on your Path. Search for 'Anaconda Prompt'. In there you will have conda. While in 'Anaconda Prompt', try 'conda list', and report what you see

Comment: Thanks @PraysonW.Daniel. When I did <conda install selenium>, from the Anaconda prompt, I was able to download and install!

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We wrote a [guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to help users with this kind of problems. Please read it to solver yours.